# Ordinary Differential Equation of Degree two

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $xy\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=\sqrt{x^2-y^2-x^2y^2-1}$

I have tried solvable by $x, y, p,$ Clairaut's.
Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Do you mean $$\sqrt{x^2-y^2-x^2y^2-1}$$ at the right hand side?

Comment: @Harsh Kumar Be careful of your edit. It might be the RHS is the one I suggested in the comment. Lets wait for the OP to respond?

Comment: @Harsh Kumar- Yes

Comment: Is it OK now or not.

Comment: @Moo So only numerical method will work for this?

Comment: @HarshKumar Yes that's the RHS

Comment: @JJacquelin Do you mean to say the Order is one, and not two? d^2y/dx^2 has order 2, but degree 1. I mentioned degree two because I thought it would be the form in which equation can be solved.

Comment: Sorry for my comment, deleted.